# Ambient module with some explicit interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

When I defined

```
declare module "my-module";
```

I am saying "You can import anything from this module" For example:

```
import {funcFuncFunc} from 'my-module';

funcFuncFunc(10); // No error here
```

But! I can't use anything imported from this module as a type.

```
import {BlahBlahBlah} from "my-module";

let a: BlahBlahBlah; // Error like "Cannot use namespace 'BlahBlahBlah' as a type.
```

If I define this interface specifically like this:

```
declare module "my-module" {
  type BlahBlahBlah = any;
}
```

Then the last example will work fine but first will break.

**Question:** Is there a way to make a definition such that I can have best of both worlds? I want to define explicit interfaces only for things I want to use as types, and everything else to be implicitly any.

So, this will work:

```
declare module "my-module" {
  type BlahBlahBlah = any;
  // + Some any Magic
}

import {BlahBlahBlah, funcFuncFunc} from 'my-module';

let a: BlahBlahBlah;
funcFuncFunc(10);
```

Comment: Try to add "export" before type or a variable.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you cannot use undefined names that implicitly resolve to `any`.

Answer (score 0):

`declare module "my-module";` is a shortcut for when you can't find an existing declaration file (.d.ts), don't have time to write one nor time to convert the module to typescript.

If you want to write a proper declaration file, the official doc is here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

You can see a live example you may be able to copy https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/random-js/index.d.ts

Be aware that if the module is simple, writing a declaration file can be longer than converting the module to typescript. (YMMV)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, though.